# Show ratio as a percentage

Tags: excel-formula

Im trying to create a ratio between 3 numbers in excel, but want it represented in a percentage.

E.g. 
    ffffffff
As you can see in the picture.. I have three totals.. I want the ratio of these three numbers.. but represented as a percentage in each of the column. So how much percent is 110.28 in comparison to 154.67 and 32.29. By hand, I know they would be 37% | 52% | 11%

[image: sample image]

Comment: What are the answers you're expecting?

Comment: @CallumDA 37% | 52% | 11%

Comment: @KashifHussain I've updated my answer - see the formula under update (at the bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on whether they're in separate cells or not - if they are, it's a simple one value over the sum of all values (if they're in A1, B1 and C1 it'll be `A1/SUM($A$1:$C$1)`, `B1/SUM($A$1:$C$1)` and `C1/SUM($A$1:$C$1)` respectively):

[image]

but I'm guessing it's all in the one cell so the first ratio would be `=LEFT(A9,FIND("|",A9,1)-2)/(LEFT(A9,FIND("|",A9,1)-2)+LEFT(RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),FIND("|",RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),1)-2)+RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,FIND("|",A9,1)+1)-1))`,

the second ratio would be `=LEFT(RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),FIND("|",RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),1)-2)/(LEFT(A9,FIND("|",A9,1)-2)+LEFT(RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),FIND("|",RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),1)-2)+RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,FIND("|",A9,1)+1)-1))`

and the third ratio would be `=RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,FIND("|",A9,1)+1)-1)/(LEFT(A9,FIND("|",A9,1)-2)+LEFT(RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),FIND("|",RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),1)-2)+RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,FIND("|",A9,1)+1)-1))` - **this is assuming it's held in A9** so if you have to put your value in another cell, you'll have to change any "A9" in my code to whatever cell you ratios are in:

[image]

Also, you have to format the cells to #.##% format but I assume you know how to do that?

**Update:**

`=TEXT(LEFT(A9,FIND("|",A9,1)-2)/(LEFT(A9,FIND("|",A9,1)-2)+LEFT(RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),FIND("|",RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),1)-2)+RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,FIND("|",A9,1)+1)-1)),"#%")&" | "& TEXT(LEFT(RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),FIND("|",RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),1)-2)/(LEFT(A9,FIND("|",A9,1)-2)+LEFT(RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),FIND("|",RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),1)-2)+RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,FIND("|",A9,1)+1)-1)),"#%") & " | " & TEXT(RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,FIND("|",A9,1)+1)-1)/(LEFT(A9,FIND("|",A9,1)-2)+LEFT(RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),FIND("|",RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,1)),1)-2)+RIGHT(A9,LEN(A9)-FIND("|",A9,FIND("|",A9,1)+1)-1)),"#%")`

Comment: Thanks. Yes i wanted seperate cells.

Comment: @KashifHussain cool. I wasn't really sure so I made a formula to give it all to you in one cell also